# Vite + Vue Router - Dynamic Imports

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite

I'm using Vite together with Vue 3 for a personal project and have `vue-router@4` for my routes. Because each of my modules uses the same set of routes, I created a helper function:

```
import { RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router'
import pluralize from 'pluralize'
import Str from '@supercharge/strings'

export function createRoutes(name: string): Array<RouteRecordRaw> {
    const plural = pluralize.plural(name)
    const path = Str(plural).trim().lower().kebab().get()
    const module = Str(plural).trim().studly().get()
    const titleSingular = Str(pluralize.singular(name)).title().get()
    const titlePlural = Str(plural).title().get()

    return [
        {
            path: `/${path}`,
            name: titlePlural,
            component: () => import(`@/views/${module}/index.vue`),
        },
        {
            path: `/${path}/:id`,
            name: titleSingular,
            component: () => import(`@/views/${module}/Single.vue`),
        },
        {
            path: `/${path}/new`,
            name: `New ${titleSingular}`,
            component: () => import(`@/views/${module}/New.vue`),
        },
    ]
}
```

The problem I'm facing however is that Vite doesn't appear to support dynamic imports.

```
3:05:29 pm [vite] warning: 
G:/Dev/world-building/client/src/router/util.ts
21 |        path: `/${path}/new`,
22 |        name: `New ${titleSingular}`,
23 |        component: () => import(`@/views/${module}/New.vue`)
   |                                ^
24 |      }
25 |    ];
The above dynamic import cannot be analyzed by vite.
See https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations for supported dynamic import formats. If this is intended to be left as-is, you can use the /* @vite-ignore */ comment inside the import() call to suppress this warning.

  Plugin: vite:import-analysis
  File: G:/Dev/world-building/client/src/router/util.ts
```

I took a look at the provided link to see the limitations however my pattern appears to match what's supported.

Why doesn't my code work? Everything appears to be fine yet I get the above warning (and an error in console when I try to visit any routes using dynamic imports).

In case it helps, the error I get in console is:

```
TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier '@/views/Galaxies/index.vue'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Vite 3.x (currently `3.0.0-alpha.7`) now supports aliases in dynamic imports. You can install it with:

```bash
npm i -D vite@alpha
```

[demo (Vite 3)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-dynamic-imports-t3jr7u?file=src%2Frouter.ts)

---

*Vite 2.x:*
Your code doesn't work because the import paths violate this rule:

> [Imports must start with `./` or `../`](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#imports-must-start-with--or-).

Replacing `@` with the resolved path should fix the problem. Assuming `@` is aliased to `<projectRoot>/src` and `router.js` is in `<projectRoot>/src`, you could replace `@` with `./`:

```js
return [
  {
    path: `/${path}`,
    name: titlePlural,
    component: () => import(`./views/${module}/index.vue`),
  },                         
  {
    path: `/${path}/:id`,
    name: titleSingular,
    component: () => import(`./views/${module}/Single.vue`),
  },                         
  {
    path: `/${path}/new`,
    name: `New ${titleSingular}`,
    component: () => import(`./views/${module}/New.vue`),
  },                         
]
```

[demo (Vite 2)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-dynamic-imports?file=src%2Frouter.ts)

Comment: I don't understand why that's an issue. I have `@` set as an alias in my vite config to `path.resolve(__dirname, './src')`.
In a previous Vue3-only project, I had lazy-loaded routes use `@` in imports and it worked just fine. Is it because these are dynamic or is it because of vite?

Comment: This is a limitation of Vite's static import analysis. It's probably too costly to implement support for imports that have multiple dynamic parts (the `@` itself would technically be a variable in the path, in addition to the part you actually want to be dynamic). The docs describe the reason as: `To help static analysis, and to avoid possible foot guns`.

Comment: Well thank you for the help here. I thought the `@` might have been the issue however I was hoping there'd be a way to keep it.

Comment: @Spedwards Vite 3.x now supports path aliases in dynamic imports. See updated answer.